# Netbeans Project Transfer 7.1.1 to 7.4

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7.1, netbeans-7.4

I cannot get my projects to transfer from my win7 (v7.1.1) and appear on my win 8.1 computer (v7.4).

There is no "export" option in 7.1.1 that I can find, and directly copying/pasting the folders from 7.1.1's workspace folder to 7.4's NetBeansProjects folder doesn't make them appear in the project window (I've tried restarted the program, scanning for external changes, and disabling the auto-scan thing)

I've tried looking at guides, but either it does not work, or options such as "Export" do not exist.

All of my projects are just basic applications (no server or database stuff). The only extremities are image packages which only a few of my programs use.

Any help appreciated.
-Austin

Comment: You neither need an "export" nor an "import". Just open the projects using "File -> Open Project"

Comment: I will try that tonight. Any specific location I need to have the file at? Or will it copy it to the projects folder for me? And I was almost positive that tying to open a file asked for a .zip. I will try it again though!

Comment: A NetBeans project is a directory not a single file. You specified that when you created the project. Very often the directory is called "nbproject" - but that is just a naming convention. The file open dialog will recognize directories that are NetBeans projects and will display them with the corresponding icon.

Comment: Yes. I copied the entire folder over. i.e. If I have a project called "helloworld" I copied the entire item over. When I got to open it, it does not recognize it as a netbeans project, simply a folder called helloworld that has folders called bin, src, assets, ect... So I am assuming it does not detect these folders as anything more than plain folder. That make sense?

Comment: You probably didn't copy the project folder, but the folder where the sources are located. A NetBeans project folder contains a `build.xml` and a sub-directory `nbproject` which in turn contains e.g. a `project.properties` and a `project.xml` (and much more): https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#ide-concepts

Comment: Wow. You were right. It has been a long time indeed it seems for me. haha. Thank you very much kind sir, or rather horse. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a lot of projects to export, then you can try to recreate them using the create project using existing sources option.

Comment: I suppose so...but I have a game I'm working on that has a LOT of code.

Comment: A lot of code = also a lot of projects? If so then I don't know the answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Project you have the option of creating the metadata folder in a different location. As long as you do not exercise that option, you should have an extra folder named "nbproject" in addition to the other files/folders in your project folder.

If you copy the entire project folder (including the nbproject subfolder) to a new machine, you can then "Open" that project folder with the "Project Open" option in the receiving machine's netbeans.

If, however, you have lost the nbproject folder (left it behind, deleted it or created it in a different location ...) you'll either need to re-create the project or find that folder.

To recreate the project, just create an empty project (not linked to any external locations) and then copy your sources into it. Then when you link it to the external sources you'll be good to go.